# windows maximize to full screen and bottom hides behind the panel

Tags: xorg, xubuntu, kubuntu, kde, xfce

I have one monitor above another.  I would like to have a panel at the top of the bottom monitor and another at the bottom of the top monitor.

Putting the panels in place works as expected.  However, when the panels are on the edge of a screen that butts up against another screen, space is not reserved for the panel when maximizing windows.  So, if I try and maximize Firefox, I can't see the "addons" bar at the bottom.

I have tested this in both kubuntu and xubuntu with similar results.  I found [a bug for KDE](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=287709) that describes the problem and a comment says:

> panels in between monitors are not supported, and this is a limitation
>   in the freedesktop specification for reserving space for things like
>   panels.

There is another forum posts that talks some about this:

http://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=102303

Is there any way to get the limitation in the specification addressed and/or are there any workarounds to make the applications maximize without being behind the panels?

Answer (score 10):

how about this:

`Settings Manager` -> `Panel` -> `Display` -> Uncheck "`Don't reserve space on borders`"

Comment: this is the correct answer, helped me :)

Answer (score 1):

Easy fix in Xubuntu 12.04 (you didn't say which edition you're using):

**Right-click** on the panel, select **Properties** (make sure it's *panel* properties rather than one of the launchers or applets *on* the panel_), then click the **Appearance** tab.  **Opacity** should be set to 100.

If panels are set to "vanish" when not mousing over them, then open windows will go right over the "invisible" panel.  Use the settings screen to keep the panel visible.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I don't think you fully grasp the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In ubuntu, you can reserve space for your panels with `xprop`, using the `_NET_WM_STRUT_PARTIAL` property (the reserved space is called strut).
The idea is to get the ID of your panel window with `xwininfo`, and feed it together with the desired coordinates into `xprop -set`.
If this answer seems to work for you, you can check out my [blogpost](http://alice-at-ubuntu.blogspot.hu/2015/01/how-to-reserve-space-for-panel-between.html) for a detailed how-to and more info on using xprop.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem as well. I have the panel at the bottom of the screen. The workaround of making the panel transparent on mouse-exit worked alright, but I noticed that when I moved the mouse all the way to the bottom of the screen, the panel would go transparent as if there was a single pixel between the panel and the bottom of the screen.

I dragged the panel up a little and then back down. After it snapped to the edge of the screen, there was no longer a pixel between it and the bottom of the screen and maximized windows now correctly maximize to the edge of the panel instead of to the edge of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround: go to Panel Settings, make the panel smaller (by dragging it) and maximize it again (there is a "maximize panel" button).
After that, windows do not go beneath it anymore.